# cannot find dll vs2010 c

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a managed exe calling a managed dll, both written in c, and compiled using vs2010 c++.

When I run the program I get error that program can't start because the dll is missing from my computer.
In the linker, under Linker->Input->Additional dependencies I have added the folder containing the dll lib.   Also, in the Linker->General section I have listed the folder under Additional include libraries.

I am clueless...

Comment: Which DLL does it say is missing?  Does that DLL actually exist?  If so, where?

Comment: The linker setting is not relevant here.  Windows needs to be able to find the DLL when it starts your program.  Make sure it is available in the build directory, where the .exe file is located.  Hard to help you beyond this, you can't write managed code in C.

Comment: The dll is one i wrote, called mcDll.  It exists in the directory I specified in the Linker->Input->Additional dependencies directory

Comment: Needs to be in the same directory as the exe, or the GAC, or you need to handle the assemblyresolve event. One of the reasons behind .net was getting rid of dll hell.

Comment: @HansPassant    That fixed the problem.  I manually copied to the DLL to the same directory with the .exe   But there must be a way to link so that the exe looks for the dll in the directory where the dll is built, no?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson   I would like to get out of hell, but I thought this was not possible (ie, to use .net) if I have a C console (not Windows) app.

Comment: Well, yes there is.  But as long as you keep talking about writing managed code in C then that will be awfully hard to explain.  Focus on the project's output setting.

Comment: @HansPassant   "Managed" code was one of those terms that I mistakenly thought meant "code that I wrote and managed", as opposed to eg, unmanaged code being a dll that I was calling written by a third party, and to which I only had the executable code.  Learn something new every day.... btw, since your comment answered my question, how do I indicate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the dll was not in the same dir as where the .exe was being executed.  However, since I didn't want to manually copy the dll each time, and since it was being used by other .exes, the better solution was to add a post-build event.

One more important note: Afraid of getting nicked with another -1 for asking a bad question, I spent a couple of hours coming up with the magic potion/incantations needed to do such a post-build copy.  Here it is.  Note the use of the macros, the /Y, and especially the quotes around the whole mess of each pathname.

```
xcopy /Y "$(SolutionDir)x64\Release\mcDll.dll" "$(SolutionDir)stream\x64\Release"
```